# NumPy where function issue. Does not traversal all piexl

Tags: python, numpy

I was using np.where to process images and set all pixels to 1 or 0.
My code is simple as below

```
import os
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import scipy.io as sio
import cv2

path='/home/aidata/segmentation_data/label'
files=os.listdir(path)
files.sort()
idx = 0
for afile in files:
    print idx
    idx = idx + 1
    file_path=os.path.join(path,afile)
    im = cv2.imread(file_path,0)
    im = np.where(im != 0, 1, 0)
    cv2.imwrite(file_path,im)
print 'finished'
```

However, after run this code I found there still have some pixels with value 2 !? I don't know what is happened here, I used np.where(im==2) to check the index of these pixels and it did return a correct result but you cannot just change them to 1..
any help?
I uploaded the a example of original image and a part of pixels value showed from Matlab.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Numpy.where returns a value. You need to assign it to something.

Comment: Reference for the `numpy.where` function [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html). Taking a look at the **Parameters** and **Returns** sections confirms what @wwii stated.

Comment: sorry I lost something when I post my code. I already return value to the image

Comment: Can you post a minimal example of `im`?

Comment: sure, I added a example in the question.

Comment: `a = np.array(((1,2,3),(0,9,1), (2,2,0))); b = np.where(a != 1, 1, 0)` works. Cannot reproduce.

Comment: look at 'im != 0'  Does it have the right pattern of true/false?

Comment: Please try reproducing the case with a small image, say, 4x4, and post both input and output.

Comment: Is the dtype of the original `im`, `np.uint8`?  After `where`, `int32`?

Comment: @hpaulj thanks for reminding me about the datatpye. It comes out that I saved the result image as .jpg and some pixels changed automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Besides finding the source of the strange error you are seeing, you could use (just tested it)

```
im2 = np.sign(im)   # avoiding replacement
cv2.imwrite(file_path,im2)
```

or more succintly

```
cv2.imwrite(file_path, np.sign(im))
```

instead of

```
im = np.where(im != 0, 1, 0)
cv2.imwrite(file_path,im)
```